# ERROR: Load into table - Invalid data in COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am importing data from CSV file into Amazon Redshift using COPY command and getting error :

```
COPY table1 FROM 's3://cucket1/table1.csv' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=aaaa;aws_secret_access_key=aaaa' 
IGNOREHEADER 1  
csv 
NULL AS '\N' 
timeformat 'auto';
```

ERROR:  Load into table 'table1' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.

my csv file looks like :

```
"id","name","created_at","updated_at"
"1","2","NULL","NULL"
"2","1","NULL","NULL"
"6","1","NULL","NULL"
"87","1","NULL","NULL"
```

When i remove NULL values from csv file, COPY command working fine.
How to handle NULL values in redshift COPY command?`enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `NULL`s have format `"NULL"`. This should work:

```
COPY table1 FROM 's3://cucket1/table1.csv' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=aaaa;aws_secret_access_key=aaaa' 
IGNOREHEADER 1  
csv 
NULL AS 'NULL' 
timeformat 'auto';
```

Also having a look into the `stl_load_errors` will give you a better idea on what's wrong.

Have you tried `select * from stl_load_errors order by starttime desc limit 100;`? This query should give you all the details about the data that could not be loaded. I suspect that in your case it was that `"NULL"` coundn't have been parsed into`TIMESTAMP` type.